# Black and white print

Tags: thesis, frontespizio, suftesi

I'm using the following package to create the titlepage of my thesis:

`\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}`

The class `suftesi` define the `sufred` colour for the title of the thesis, like this:

`\definecolor{sufred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}`

I need to print the pdf in black and white. There exist a command for the preamble in order to get **all** the text black and white?

This is the `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\input{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

This is `titlepage.tex`:

```
\begin{frontespizio}
\Universita{x}
\Logo{logo1}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\end{frontespizio}
```

EDIT: 
Somebody told me to redefine the `sufred` colour. How can I do it?

EDIT1: the package `frontespizio` create a `main-frn.tex` file and the procedure to compile everything is:

```
pdflatex main
pdflatex main-frn
pdflatex main
```

This is my main-frn.tex:

```
%% This file has been automatically generated by `frontespizio'.
%% Don't use it as a model for a new frontispiece, use the
%% `frontespizio' environment in you document instead.

\documentclass [titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper,textwidth=312pt,includehead,textheight=624pt,right=90pt,vmarginratio=1:2]{geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nowrite,infront,suftesi]{frontespizio}
\nofiles 
\fontoptionnormal 
\Universita{x}
\Logo[1.5cm]{logo1}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\begin {document}
\preparefrontpagesuftesi
\end {document}
```

Comment: Could you please create a complete compilable [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)? It should start at `\documentclass` and end at `\end{document}`. As a dirty solution you could define all colours to either black or white. In case of your `sufred` this could be done with `\definecolor{sufred}{gray}{0}`.

Comment: And if it's just about printing (not about displaying on a computer) you could as well just print with the printer configuration for black and white in the printer's driver. If you print it in a print shop most/all of them give black and white as an option.

Comment: @Skillmon Where do I have to write `\definecolor{sufred}{gray}{0}`? I've tried in the preamble but didn't work.

Comment: Then try it after `\begin{document}` or just before it. If it doesn't work there then the definition of `sufred` is done later (maybe inside the title creation) in which case you'd have to hook into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to change the title color is with a `\Preambolo` declaration:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{frontespizio}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\fronttitlecolor}{black}}
\Universita{x}
%\Logo{logo1}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title colour is defined by the macro `\fronttitlecolor` which's content is `Maroon` so

1. `sufred` is not the right colour to change and
2. just redefining `\fronttitlecolor` is simpler

So the following sets the title colour to black:

```
\documentclass [titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper,textwidth=312pt,includehead,textheight=624pt,right=90pt,vmarginratio=1:2]{geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nowrite,infront,suftesi]{frontespizio}
\nofiles 
\fontoptionnormal 
\Universita{x}
\Logo[1.5cm]{example-image-a}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\def\fronttitlecolor{black}
\begin {document}
\preparefrontpagesuftesi
\end {document}
```

Alternatively, you could use `\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}` as noted in one of my previous comments. Insert it just at the beginning of your main file (prior to `\documentclass`) this way, it should work with your automatic setup. Note that this way eliminates more colours than just the title.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
\documentclass [titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper,textwidth=312pt,includehead,textheight=624pt,right=90pt,vmarginratio=1:2]{geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nowrite,infront,suftesi]{frontespizio}
\nofiles 
\fontoptionnormal 
\Universita{x}
\Logo[1.5cm]{example-image-a}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\begin {document}
\preparefrontpagesuftesi
\end {document}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. The only drawback is that everytime i compile main.tex I've to reinsert `\def\fronttitlecolor{black}` in main-frn.tex. Thank you

Comment: @zar The `-frn` file should *never* be edited. This is not the correct way to do what you'd like to.

Comment: This worked like a charm... I have a custom class file, and to override all colours, I used `\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}` right before `\LoadClass`

Answer (score 0):

If you using the package `color`, then please use `monochrome` in optional argument, it will turn all colors into Black/White, usage is:

```
\usepackage[monochrome]{color}
```

If you not use this package, then provide the `MWE` for your code...

Said suggestion is working fine with your codes, hope the color problem may lies in your image file, check the below code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{color}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{frontespizio}
\Preambolo{\renewcommand{\fronttitlecolor}{black}}
\Universita{x}
%\Logo{logo1}
\Divisione{y}
\Corso{n}
\Titoletto{f}
\Titolo{titolo tesi}
\Candidato[1]{as}
\Relatore{va}
\Annoaccademico{2020}
\end{frontespizio}

\color{blue}
Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition: If the package is loaded by one of your packages or the class, you might use the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{color}` prior to the loadtime.

Comment: I've try to insert in the preamble `\usepackage[monochrome]{color}` but nothing changed.

Comment: Hope the problem may lies in your image "sample-frn.eps", in text part my suggestion working fine, also I've updated my answer...